# Error while trying to load font family "packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons": SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Tags: flutter, github-pages, flutter-cupertino, github-pages-deploy-action

I have an issue with github pages and flutter web.
When i launch Github Pages i have this issue :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0v3Q.png)
And i have a blank page.
It's weird because it works well in local.
Here is my Github Actions worflow :

```yaml
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
          flutter-version: '3.10.6'

      - name: Update environment variables
        run: |
          printf "FIREBASE_API=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_API }}\n" > .env 
          printf "FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}\n" >> .env
          printf "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}\n" >> .env
          printf "FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}\n" >> .env
          printf "FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}\n" >> .env
          printf "FIREBASE_APP_ID=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_APP_ID }}\n" >> .env
          printf "FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID }}\n" >> .env

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Run build runner
        run: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

      - name: Build web
        run: flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --base-href /portfolio/

      - name: Upload production-ready build files
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./build/web

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./build

      - name: Deploy to gh-pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./build
```

Here you can find my pubpsec.yaml file :

```yaml
name: portfolio
description: Mon portfolio en flutter.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.5
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  carousel_slider: ^5.2.1
  url_launcher: ^7.1.12
  envied: ^1.3.0+3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  envied_generator: ^0.3.0+3

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/
    - lib/assets/images/
    - lib/assets/docs/
    - lib/assets/data/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: NeueKonstantGrotesk
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/assets/fonts/NeueKonstantGrotesk-Book.otf
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Thank you in advance, I have already spent several hours trying to solve this problem.

I tried, to add a `flutter clean` in the workflow.
I tried, to change the cupertino_icons pkg
I tried, to change the --web-renderer option in the build command